How to share Text and Uri to Facebook using .net maui?
I have built a product catalogue app, where I am trying to implement share feature, primarily targeting to share to Whatsapp and facebook. Shared content has 2 links in it. One URI for the Product itself, and another is the Playstore app download URI. I tried below in .net maui
await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
 {
     Text = $"Great product, {strProductURI}",
     Title = "Shared from App",
     Uri = strPlayStoreUri
 });

In Android, This works fine when shared to Whatsapp but when shared to facebook only one of the Uri goes through and the text is also lost. Any help in this regard?   I havn't tried in iOS, as it is not in priority as of now.
